# yum install , Update returns 404 error in centos 6.6

Tags: centos6, yum

yum doesnt work at all,

yum install , update doesnt work gives below error

```
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: archive.linux.duke.edu
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/SCL/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: scl. Please verify its path and try again
```

centos version 6.6
python 2.6

Please help me if any one knows about this.

**EDIT1:**

When tried with ,

```
 yum --enablerepo=extras install centos-release-scl
```

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Error getting repository data for extras, repository not found

Got the above error

Comment: Try `yum --enablerepo=extras install centos-release-scl`

Comment: Hi Bhurhan Khalid, what does the above command do..?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid , when i try above command , i got an error . I pasted in the question EDIT1

Answer (score 2):

My solution on Centos 7 was to remove `yum` cache.

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you need to configure some files related to yum,

I tried to search about this problem on net and found some solutions which worked for other people.

Try this links for solution.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/15506/error-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomdxm.html

https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2321

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

In yum.conf.d, find repo which is using this broken url and toggle enabled flag to 0, to not use this repo

```
grep -ril "<url to find>" ./
```